# Escape special characters in MySQL using C# and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have a ASP.Net web page with a MySQL back end. The blog content on this site is populated from the MySQL database. When ever I wanted to write a blog entry, I would open MySQL Workbench, right click on the table and select "edit data" and then proceed to type my entry. Well, now I'm working on a C# application that will allow me to write a blog entry so that I don't have to open workbench everytime. Everything so far is working great except for one minor issue: special characters.

**==Example==**

In textBox1 I will write the following,

> I can tell you that this won't work because of the apostrophe

My code looks like this (may be a little off as I'm writing this from memory, but it does work):

```
MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand("",conn);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogEntry (entryText) VALUE (" + textBox1.text + ");";
...
```

This works and the text is inserted into my table. But when I pull it back out and bind it to a DataGridView I see this:

> I can tell you that this won

and that's it (or I see some wierd formatting or something).

**==SUMMARY==**

I know it has something to do with the apostrophe not being escaped. So my questions are:

1) In C#, is there a way to go through the entire text in textBox1 and replace all special characters (') with escapes (\') so that they show correctly when pulled from the database?

2) I read about some people using stored procedures or parameters in the INSERT statements. Would that work for me and how exactly would I do that (I'm having some trouble finding examples of my specific case)?

Thanks for any help, ideas, links, etc.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using Mysql client library, You can use this functions

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString("YOUR DATA STRING")
```

In your case:

```
MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand("",conn);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogEntry (entryText) VALUE ('"+MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(entryText)+"');";
```

Comment: Now, how do I un-escape the data I get from MySQL from a select statement? I am seeing that data has escaped double quotes and escaped forward slashes...

Answer (score 17):

It would be better to use a parameterized query.  That way you would not need to escape characters, and it would (more importantly) help prevent an SQL injection attack.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogEntry (entryText) VALUES (@myvalue)"
```

And then something along the lines of:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myvalue", TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameterized SQL at least, otherwise your attempts at sanitizing input could leave you open to SQL Injection.

[Check here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters)

Something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogEntry (entryText) VALUE (?entryText)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?entryText", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 255, textBox1.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expression to replace special chars. Also .Net provide RegEx class which has Escape method to replace special chars which Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes.

```
MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand("",conn);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogEntry (entryText) VALUE (" + Regex.Escape(textBox1.text) + ");";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to escape any unwanted characters. Suppose the characters inside the curly brackets are the characters you want to avoid.

```
char[] charsToTrim = { 'O','R', '`', ' ', '\'', '=', '1' , '-', ';'};  

string value = " `admin` OR 1=1;-- ";

lblescape.Text = value.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

The Trim(char[]) will avoid all the unwanted characters but it has its own disadvantages such as you cannot use the character "O" or "R" even though you want them to use, but I guess you can make some arrangements to it..

Comment: If I read this correct, you are showing how to remove characters, not escape them. OP want's to have the "'" character make it to the db and not get cut off.

Comment: Oh! my bad dude, i was just working late, and i didn't go through all the text, i just read the title and other random replies, i didn't meant to misguide anyone..

Answer (score 0):

You would absolutely want to use parameters in this case.  It will avoid the escaping issue and also protect you against SQL injection attacks (to which this code is currently vulnerable).

To use parameters, your code would look like:

```
MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand("",conn);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogEntry (entryText) VALUE (?entryText);";
```

Then afterwards, you would initialize the parameter.  Something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?entryText", textBox1.Text);
```