# How can I replace all instances of the backslash character?

Tags: c#, mysql, escaping

I am trying to insert values that will be used for a richtextbox into mysql fields. Since mysql will not treat `\\` or `\r` literally, I want to replace all occurrences of `\` with `\\`. I have tried:

```
mystring.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

but it's not working for `\r`,`\n`, etc. How else can I do this?

**EDIT:**
My input looks like:

> \rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\r\n

and my output should look like:

> \\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\r\n

Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Please re-phrase with more examples of input and output.

Comment: Try: Regex.Escape(mystring)

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357831/escape-special-characters-in-mysql-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Regex.Escape(mystring);
```

See: [Escape special characters in MySQL using C# and ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357831/escape-special-characters-in-mysql-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

Example:

```
var data = "this is \n a \r\ntest";
var result = Regex.Escape(data); // this\ is\ \n\ a\ \r\ntest

//replace escaped spaces
Console.Write(result.Replace(@"\ ", " ")); // this is \n a \r\ntest
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var mystring = @"\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\r\n";
mystring = mystring.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

yields

```
\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\r\\n
```

The only things I can think of are:

- Have the backslashes already been unescaped in `mystring`?
- Are you taking the result of .Replace(), and not just keeping `mystring`